# How to compute the SOA of a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet, safe-operating-area

Is there any tool to check if a MOSFET is within its SOA or not for a given operating condition?

Comment: It's normally just a graph in the datasheet.

Comment: The graph is only for a given temperature. Want to know if any tool is there which will convert the operational condition and calculate the point in the graph

Comment: Please numerically describe a situation where you feel that the SOA curve in the data sheet cannot yield what you want to know.

Comment: I'm primarily considering two test condition. First a MOSFET is  used to switching (either ON/OFF) a capacitive load (100uF) from a line voltage of 100V. The second case is of a MOSFET used as a switch in a DC-DC converter (boost converter).

Comment: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/mosfet-safe-operating-area-and-hot-swap-circuits.html